# How to change a textview text with a delay without using threads in android?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, delay

I need to sequentially show a changing text with 1 second or half a second between changes. How can i achieve this without using threads in android?

Comment: Threads would not work anyway, only the UI Thread may modify UI elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a handler and a runnable in your activity, fairly simple

```
    Handler textNextHandler = new Handler(); 

    final Runnable textTimer = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
           // ROTATE YOUR TEXT HERE THEN TELL IT HOW LONG TO DELAY UNTIL NEXT
           textNextHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);  
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        textNextHandler.postDelayed(textTimer,500); 
    }       

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        textNextHandler.removeCallbacks(textTimer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Comment: Can you please show me a small example of that? I seem to have the wrong idea about how a Runnable works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))